# Is there a way to obtain a "reference" to a value type field through reflection?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection, reference, field

I'm trying to make a tool for Unity, which will display values from fields that have my custom `[ObserveField]` attribute in the Editor window. I've got to a point where I have a list of needed `FieldInfo`'s but here's where my problem comes - at the moment I have to use `fieldInfo.GetValue(fieldObject)` to obtain the values and if I do it for every field in the list, in a GUI loop, it's gonna slow down significantly and I assume it's not the best idea.

I know that if a field would be of reference type, there would be no problem, but for now only value types will be possible to "observe". Is there a way to somehow obtain the "reference" to the actual value, not the copy? Maybe something like a c++ pointer to a memory address of a field value?

Objects containing the observed fields can be of any type so I cannot just do `obj.someField` because I get them at runtime by checking which objects (from some list that doesn't matter here) have fields with my attribute.

Comment: Get them in OnEnable so you get the references once and keep them as long as your UI is open.

Comment: onvalidate <-- if you just wanna check on editor value change , you can try it

Comment: I have references to objects containing the fields I need, that's not the problem. Any type can use this custom attribute on its fields so I cannot simply call `someObj.someField` as the type is unknown and amount of observed fields may vary. `ClassA` can have 2 fields with `[ObserveField]` attribute and `ClassB` only one, so I can only check IF an object has one and if it has, do `fieldInfo.GetValue(someObj)` on each of them to get their values.

Comment: You can use a dynamic method or a compiled expression. If they were properties you could generate a delegate off the getter

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you, I'll look into these. Do you have by any chance an example of usage of any of these to achieve something similiar?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-define-and-execute-dynamic-methods and https://particular.net/blog/10x-faster-execution-with-compiled-expression-trees and https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/17807/get-a-strongly-typed-delegate-to-a-method-or-property-via-reflection

Comment: From what I see it only applies to properties, so no luck with plain fields I suppose. I'll restrict the attribute usage to properties only then.